# JavaScript - HTML form to JSON (empty values) and format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I know there are similar questions out there but I couldn't find the answer for my question.

I have a simple form and a button.

```
<form id="myForm" class="vertically-centered">
    <p> Name </p>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="formName"> 

    <p> Address</p> 
    <input type="text" name="address" id="formAddress">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitFormBtn">
</form>
```

When the button is pressed, i want to transform the inserted data into JSON so I can send an AJAX request later.

I want to get something like this

```
[{"name": name, "address":address}]
```

and to achieve that, I'm using `serializeArray()`

```
document.getElementById ("submitFormBtn").addEventListener ("click", submitFormData, false);
function submitFormData(){
    var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
    console.log(formData);
}
```

but when I print `formData` i get empty values and this format

```
[{"name":"name","value":""},{"name":"address","value":""}]
```

Any idea what might be wrong ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: And why do you stringify it to JSON, there's no good reason to do so ?

Comment: And serializing a form will give you an object that looks like that, as that's what expected when sending a form, there should be empty values.

Comment: Please post your code. `serializeArray` should work the way you want, so you must be using it incorrectly.

Comment: If the user has filled in the form inputs, the values shouldn't be empty.

Comment: @Barmar - and they won't be, but the OP writes that he wants `[{"name": name, "address":address}]` without the values, and that's probably because it's easier to access the JSON that way, but it shouldn't be JSON at all, it should be sent as a form/www-encoded etc.

Comment: Ahh, right. The format he wants is not how `serializeArray` works. Read the documentation, it shows what the array should look like.

Comment: I thought his complaint was that he's getting `value: ""` instead if `value: "enteredvalue"`

Comment: @blex That's not JSON, that's x-www-form-urlencoded format.

Comment: @Barmar - so did I at first, but I think it is that he's trying to access the JSON in a sain way, using the names as keys to get the values, but if he stops encoding to JSON, it works out of the box

Comment: Thanks for the help so far !  I reformulated the question. The problem is both getting empty values (would like to understand why), as well as, the wrong format (i understand i cannot use `serializeArray()`).

Comment: The empty values is probably because nothing is typed in the inputs, otherwise you'd get the value. The format is correct, it's exactly what you want when you're going to send it with ajax.

Comment: I'm 100% sure i typed something in the inputs. I have no idea why the fields are empty.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ypsyt8tq/ - put that submit button inside the form

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the suggestion ! That was a typo when pasting the code. Sorry.

Comment: @adeneo I'm starting to think the problem isn't related with `serializeArray()`. Using your code i get `name=&address=`

Comment: That's because that's how `serialize` represents it, as a string, not an array

Comment: Right, I understand that. I was talking about the empty values after "="

Comment: I found out the error ! It was not related with `serializeArray()`. All the solutions are working fine now. Thanks for all the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **clean** JavaScript solution:

Set the **length** of the form:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#myForm"); // document.getElementById("myForm") is also working
var formLength = form.length;
```

- form[0] first  tag
- form[1] second  tag
- ...
- form[0].name `<input name="name"...>`
- form[0].value `<input value="inputValue"...>`
- ...

Set an **object** to store these dates:

```
var obj = {};
```

After clicking the button go through the form and store the dates in the object:

```
for(var i = 0; i < formLength; i += 1) {
    obj[form[i].name] = form[i].value;
}
```

At last **stringify** your object:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcae8p8f/1/

Comment: Thanks ! All solutions seem to work fine but I keep getting empty input values from the form.

Comment: I just found out the error was not related with `serializeArray()`. Anyway, I like this solution ! It's simple, readable and the output is exactly what I want. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a new object with each pair of key / value:

```js
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var res = {};
    $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function() {
        res[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    alert( JSON.stringify(res) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" class="vertically-centered">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name" id="formName" />
    <p>Address</p> <input type="text" name="address" id="formAddress" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Note:** My code returns: `{name: "name", address: "address"}`

But you said you wanted an array: `[{name: "name", address: "address"}]`

If so, wrap `res` with square brackets: `alert( JSON.stringify( [res] ) );`

Comment: I tested your snippet in my code and I still get the empty values `{"name":"","address":""}` . Probably the problem isn't related with `serializeArray()`...

Comment: @adeneo 's solution is actually the standard way to do it, though. _(why bother trying to make it this format?)_. **PS:** your issue is weird, is there any way you could create a JS Fiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I just made this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3g04wv2f/ but I couldn't reproduce the error... The fields are correct here.

Comment: @Let_IT_roll The fields are correct? I'm not getting any result from your JS Fiddle because your inputs don't have a `name` attribute, only an ID (fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/r5L7ooe3/).

Comment: I forgot to save the fiddle ! I had the `name` attributes and I was getting that output. I have no idea why I cannot do the same locally. Btw, I'm running a node.js server on localhost. Maybe it be because of that ?

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I finally spotted the error. It was not related with `serializeArray()`. All the suggested solutions work like a charm.